# How do you get the sum of values by day, but day in columns SQL

Tags: sql, sum, vertica, calculation

I have a table that looks like below where day, client_name and order_value are stored/

```
select day, client_name, order_value
from sample_table
```

| day | client_name | order_value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-01-01 | A | 100 |
| 2021-01-01 | A | 100 |
| 2021-01-02 | A | 200 |
| 2021-01-03 | A | 100 |
| 2021-01-01 | B | 300 |
| 2021-01-01 | B | 400 |
| 2021-01-01 | C | 500 |
| 2021-01-02 | C | 500 |
| 2021-01-02 | C | 500 |

and I want to get the sum of order_value per client by day, but days in columns.
Basically, I want my result to come out something like this.

| client_name | 2021-01-01 | 2021-01-02 | 2021-01-03 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 200 | 200 | 100 |
| B | 700 | Null | Null |
| C | 500 | 1000 | Null |

Comment: How many columns do you want?? There's 365 days **EVERY YEAR**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know what the days are, you can use conditional aggregation:

```
select client_name,
       sum(case when date = '2021-01-01' then order_value end) as date_20210101,
       sum(case when date = '2021-01-02' then order_value end) as date_20210102,
       sum(case when date = '2021-01-03' then order_value end) as date_20210103
from t
group by client_name ;
```

If you don't know the specific dates (i.e., you want them based on the data or a variable number), then you need to use dynamic SQL.  That means that you construct the SQL statement as a string and then execute it.

Comment: Thank you this will do!